# perl hash of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am trying to access elements of an array which is part of a hash.

```
for my $idx ( 0 .. $#vss ) {
    push (@{$vsnhash->{$vss[$idx]}}, $vsports[$idx]);
}
print Dumper(\%$vsnhash);

($VAR1 = {
      'name2' => [
                   '8001',
                   '8002'
                 ],
      'name1' => [
                   '8000'
                 ]
    };
```

I an able to access the keys with a foreach loop:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %$vsnhash ) {
print "$key\n";
}
```

How do I access the array of port numbers ('8001' , '8002') within the hash?
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while (my ($k, $v) = each %$vsnhash) {
    print "$k: @$v\n";
}
```

Comment: Wow. I have no idea how this works but it's cool to learn new stuff :)

Comment: @FailedDev: It's fairly simple actually. `each` is like `keys` but gives you key and value at the same time. `@$v` is short for `@{$v}` and dereferences an array reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach my $key ( keys %$vsnhash ) {
   print "$key\n";
   foreach my $port (@{$vsnhash->{key}}){
      print "Port $port\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Basically correct, but you've got some syntax errors.  Should be:
`foreach my $port (@{$vsnhash->{$key}}){` instead of `foreach my $port (@{$vsnhash{key}}){`

Answer (score 1):

```
$vsnhash{name2}->[0];   #8001
$vsnhash{name2}->[1];   #8002
$vsnhash{name1}->[0];   #8000
```

Code wise:

```
foreach my $key (sort keys %vsnhash) {
   foreach my $index (0..$#{$key}) {
      print "\$vsnhash{$key}->[$index] = " . $vsnhash{$key}->[$index] . "\n";
   }
}
```

The `$#{$key}` means the last entry in the array `@{$key`}. Remember that `$key` is a reference to an array while `@{$key}` is the array itself.